# Prestashop 1.6 override feature.php class

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to override feature.php class and add custom field. Let's admit that prestashop documentation is not really good. I found tutorial how to override product.php class but difference between product and feature classes is that feature class don't have constructor class. So, I don't know how to add custom field.

Also, when prestashop updates mysql database structure?

**UPDATE 1**

```
<?php
Class Feature extends FeatureCore
{

    public function __constructor()
    {
        self::$definition['fields']['category'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_INT);
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle is the same just like for the Product class. The Feature class inherits the constructor from ObjectModel class.

PrestaShop does not update the mysql database structure. This is a thing that you must do.

Comment: I've updated my first post with override class. So that should work? I've also updated my database with new "category" column.

Comment: You must use the same parameters to the constructor as the parent one: $id = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null and to pass them to the parent::__construct().